# Meaning of 祭り as a suffix

Tags: meaning, slang

I'm watching an anime in which characters often use 祭り, but I'm not sure about its meaning; here's occourrences from the first three episodes:

1. ままた来た！美人祭り…。ヘンリエッタさん
2. なんだとこのムッツリスケベ祭りめっ。僕はムッツリじゃない
3. このぉ青春真っ盛り祭りめ
4. うるせ！この女の子にモテモテ王子祭りめっ
5. じゃ冒険コンティニュー祭りといくか！
6. 難所越え祭り

I know 祭り [can mean](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%A5%AD) "galore", as in "many [of something]", and this seems to fit examples 1 (context: many beautiful girls entering a room). It can also mean "festival", which I think can fit maybe 3 (more lines for context):

> Shiroi: アカツキさんその「主君」ってのやめようよ。シロエにしない？
>
> Akatsuki: じゃあ私の事もアカツキって呼び捨てにして。
>
> Naotsugu: このぉ青春真っ盛り祭りめ。はぁ？何だよそれ。

like "How you are beahaving is a festival of youth", and maybe 4:

> サイコー！ってな感じでしょ？
>
> おぱんつの次くらいにはな。
>
> 直継先輩女の子の前でそういう事言わないで下さい。
>
> うるせ！この女の子にモテモテ王子祭りめっ。
>
> まぁ…確かにモテモテですけど。うう許さんぞソウジ！

like the character is very popular with girls, so it's like a festival of popularity, or as "galore" meaning it's very popular? Which sounds kinda stretched to me, though.

For the other examples, I tried also looking at [weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%A5%AD%E3%82%8A), but I wasn't really able to understand what 祭り means in them; more lines for context:

2)

> 会社に可愛い娘が全くいないってのが悩みだがな。
>
> んなどうでもいいじゃん。
>
> なんだとこのムッツリスケベ祭りめっ
>
> 僕はムッツリじゃない。
>
> この世界には２種類の男がいる。‌開放的なオープンスケベと内向的なムッツリスケベ！‌

5. 

> あ…私の方こそその…ありがとう…。
>
> え？何が？その…助けてくれようとして…。
>
> じゃ冒険コンティニュー祭りといくか！

6. After the characters just got out of a dungeon:

> …すごい。風が冷たい…。
>
> でも気持ちいいぞ。
>
> やっと抜けたな。難所越え祭りだぜ！
>
> …綺麗だ。すっげぇな！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We sometimes use 〇〇祭り to call or describe (non-religious, non-traditional) events where you can see a lot of something. 〇〇祭り is also popular as the name of a sale/campaign (e.g., [山崎春のパンまつり](https://www.yamazakipan.co.jp/campaign/spring/index.html)).

Among your examples, 美人祭り seems relatively straightforward because there are indeed many 美人. The other ones seem unnatural, and should be taken as jokes. These probably represent this character's idiosyncratic way of describing something emphatically. (If lots of コンティニュー or 難所越え were happening, saying コンティニュー祭り or 難所越え祭り would not be wrong.)